# Set an image of 32*32 as cursor in Vue-Echarts

Tags: javascript, css, echarts

I want to set a custom image of size 32*32 as a cursor in Echarts.
I was able to change the type of cursor to the available cursors of CSS.

But I want to set to a custom image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the custom cursor in css like this

```
cursor: url('path-to-image.png'), auto;
```

Also in [this](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/#article-header-id-1) article you can read more about the css cursor.